# ffmpeg can't create mfx session to use Intel Arc GPU

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, gpu, intel-graphics

I'm attempting to use ffmpeg with my new Intel Arc A380 GPU. I am using a build off the master branch. I specifically want to test and utilize the GPU's hardware accelerated encoders for H264, HEVC, and AV1. Whenever I run the following command
`ffmpeg -i test.mkv -c:a copy -c:v av1_qsv test-out.mkv`
the program spits out the following error.

```
ffmpeg version N-109469-g62da0b4a74-20230101 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.90_cf9beb1)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-ffbuild-linux-gnu- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --enable-libxcb --enable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-mbedtls --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --disable-libmfx --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --disable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libdrm --enable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags=-pie --extra-libs='-ldl -lgomp' --extra-version=20230101
  libavutil      57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100
  libavcodec     59. 55.103 / 59. 55.103
  libavformat    59. 34.102 / 59. 34.102
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 53.100 /  8. 53.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'test.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 02:52:34.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6169 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      VARIANT_BITRATE : 0
      DURATION        : 02:52:33.132000000
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      VARIANT_BITRATE : 0
      DURATION        : 02:52:34.069000000
File 'test-out.mkv' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> av1 (av1_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[av1_qsv @ 0x560f656b2200] Error creating a MFX session: -9.
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

I cannot find any info on what the error code -9 means. As far as I can tell, the GPU and relevant drivers are all installed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue was related to my drivers not being properly built and loaded. I was specifically missing the necessary kernel headers for the OEM kernel specified in [this document provided by Intel for using the Arc GPU](https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-jammy-arc.html) (the kernel version as of time of writing is `linux-image-5.17.0-1019-oem`). Without the headers, the DKMS modules were not being built when requested to be installed with apt, and thus the driver was not loadable or useable, finally resulting in the unknown error being unknowable.

Always get your kernel headers!